# Possible to Return Set of Values in SQL Server without Return Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here's my situation, I have a table of values that is used to create various reports. I need an `ORDER BY` in order to group the info the way I need it.

```
SELECT 
    id, indate, group, lase, first, rank 
FROM 
    this_table
WHERE 
    group = 'SomeGroup'
ORDER BY 
    last, first, indate
```

I can't use a view because it won't allow the order by. I was hoping I could create a stored procedure to return the result table I want, but without the extra return value.

I've read the comments, and I understand what a view is.
I guess the real problem is that I need to get the output into an Excel sheet, and I can only import Views, however I need the data sorted in my output.

Comment: Just explicitly include the `order by` when you execute the query.

Comment: What extra return value are you talking about? Procedures in SQL Server can **optionally** return an integer but they don't have to (well they seem to implicitly return a `0` if nothing else is specified but you don't need to use that anywhere).

Comment: I don't see any actual problem described here.

Comment: I guess the real problem is that I need to get the output into an Excel sheet, and I can only import Views, however I need the data sorted in my output.

Answer (score 2):

A view is a passive object that just behaves like a table, but is really the result of a query (un-ordered, as you noticed). The view does *do* anything by itself. It's when you retrieve the data from the view that you apply your ORDER BY condition(s). The standard way you'd get data out would be by putting your logic in a stored procedure. Alternatively, if you are querying the data ad hoc, you don't even need to use a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create View MyView as
  SELECT id, indate, group, lase, first, rank 
  FROM this_table
    WHERE group = 'SomeGroup';
```

then

```
select * from MyView
order by last, first, indate;
```

Comment: The issue that I need a View to export the data to Excel.  Creating a view is the easy part, trying to figure out how to get it sorted and into Excel is where I'm having issue.  I was hoping that if I could get a Stored Procedure to only return the data set that I could use the stored procedure.

Comment: you can write query into excel? what is the problem? dont over-complicate it

Comment: Yeah, I JUST found it, I had to expand the Advanced Options.  All good.